# Do non-archery abilities that don't specify melee affect archery?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

The *Double Daggers* abilities...

> **Bloodied Prey** *Passive* : Your strikes cut deeper into any foe whose
>   current health is lower than your own.
>
> **Sneak Attack** *Passive* :  Attacks upon a target's back or flank are much
>   more likely to be killing blows.
>
> **Dance of Death** *Passive* :    You regain Stamina with every kill, the better
>   to continue your assault.

...don't specifically mention that they're for melee only; for an archer these would be very nice bonuses to have as well, even if you have to take a few duff levels in daggers to get them.

But do they work for archery attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but skills (active and passive) which don't mention a weapontype should work for every weapon.

There is a [**thread on gamefaq**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718650-dragon-age-inquisition/70837715) where the OP asks for critical damage vs. armor penetatrion vs flanking damage "Assuming playing an archer and using sneak attack".
Nobody in this thread says something about "Archer with the Sneak Attack Passive wont work" or something like that.

And [**another thread**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718650-dragon-age-inquisition/70830311) where someone says

> As long as something doesn't say that its for one weapon or another then
>   it works on everything.

There is nothing to be found about this on [**Dragon Age Wikia**](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_Attack).

Comment: This is true, you can edit your answer to "100% sure". Remember in multiplayer, both Assassin/Alchemist (double dagger) and Hunter/Archer (bow) have some similar skills like Sneak Attack, Bloody Prey...). They all work!

Comment: Yea you're right, i didn't think about the multiplayer classes